# checking if folder exist and can be shown to user

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I would like to check if specific directory path exist in the system and that user can be aware of this path considering his permissions.

`System::IO::Directory::Exists(path)`  return false if the user does not have permissions to READ the directory.

However having read permissions and possibility to see that folder exist is not the same.

For example in Explorer I can see on system drive `C:`  a folder `Documents and Settings`.   when I check it with `Directory::Exists`, it return `false`, as I cannot open the directory with my user permissions, however I can still see that directory on the list in explorer, which means that I have the access to see it.

Is there a method to check if user can be aware of the directory existence despite lack of access to read it ?

Comment: could you enumerate the parent directory?

Comment: as a workaround I could try to check first parent directory, list its content and see if the folder exist in the retrieved list, but It does not seem to be the best way to do it.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?